# What's the DataContext of TabControl.ItemTemplate?

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate

Given the following XAML:

```
<TabControl DataContext="{StaticResource mainVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding MovableVM.Docked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentTitle}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I expected both `DataTemplate`s to have the same `DataContext` with the expected result that the actual items from the ItemsSource (a `UserControl` implementing the interface IMovable, see below) being displayed within separate tabs and the header of each tab to display the contents of the property ContentTitle of the same item.

The `IMovable` object *is* displayed as expected, but the binding to the ContentTitle is *not* working for the header. If I change the the binding in the `ContentTemplate`, like so...

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ContentTitle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

...I do get the contents of the ContentTitle property instead of the item, so the property itself is bindable.

Here's the `IMovable` interface:

```
public interface IMovable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string ContentTitle { get; }
}
```

So my question is: Is there a different DataContext in the ItemTemplate (if so, what is it?) or is there another reason the binding in the ItemTemplate isn't working as I expect?

<strike>**Update:**
I've created a small example application that shows the problem clearly. If things had worked as expected, there would be a text below each Ellipse in each tab, and the DataContext of the Ellipse would not be null. It can be downloaded here: [Example App](http://www.codezeal.com/stackoverflow/WpfApplication2.zip)</strike>

**Update**
It works if using a custom class `Foo::DependencyObject` and making the ContentTitle property into a DependencyProperty. Though changing the property in the original class does not work. I need to sleep on this....

**Update**
I've narrowed down the problem, but the findings are not at all what I expected. [WpfApplication2](http://www.codezeal.com/stackoverflow/WpfApplication2.zip) shows that adding items to the ItemsSource that are either POCO or derived from DependedcyObject works as expected. However, items derived from UserControl do not give the expected result. I would appreciate if someone you have a look at it. Simply run the application and you'll see that one Tab header is missing the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the DataTemplate will see an object witch inherits from Visual. This type of object do not need any visual representation through a DataTemplate. There is a discussion about it on this post.

[DataTemplate DataType property doesn't work on types inherited from Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/6254c7ff-5ab9-4949-93e8-99fddc6534cd)

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the ItemContainerStyle rather than the ItemTemplate worked for me:

```
<TabControl 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=SelectedIndex}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Items}" 
    TabStripPlacement="Left"  
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=ShowTabs, Converter={StaticResource    _trueToVisibleConverter}}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

According to the following MSDN post, the problem was that I was trying to add the UIElement to which I was binding to two different places in the visual tree (the content area and the header area).  See the post for a better explanation.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0a4622ac-5990-4b6e-bf38-0acb10cd68c7/

Answer (score 0):

I need the vm code as well to be sure, but looks like the context is inside the main vm and not the child vm's that represents each tab item, the content template context is the main vm and the item template context s each tab vm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same. So if you bind to `{Binding}` in `ContentTemplate` you would bind to the object itself.

In your case: `ItemTemplate` has an `IMovable` object as data context, and indeed `ContentTemplate` has the same data context: An `IMovable` object.

You may have thought that `ItemTemplate` would *select* another data context. That is not the case.

Comment: If they were, it would have worked as expected. Please see the example application now linked in the original post.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I didn't understand you correctly. Do you want the ContentPresenter to display the object itself or the object's title property?

Comment: I want the ContentPresenter to display the object itself, and the ItemPanel to displaying a property of the same object. I've update the original post with an example showing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `ItemTemplate`'s `DataTemplate`, not `ItemPanel` to show the property of the object's property.